# Access intermediary model values Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple question. using the example from django above. How can i get  for example the invite_reason from Person on a Group ? or all joined dates to all groups from that person ? thanks.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to query your `Membership` model for that, like so:

```
memberships = Membership.objects.filter(person=person, group=group)
for membership in memberships:
    membership.invite_reason
```

Alternately, you could query it based on the relation:

```
memberships = person.membership_set.filter(group=group)
for membership in memberships:
    membership.invite_reason
```