# Getting the last member of a group on an intermediary M2M

Tags: django, django-models

If we look at the existing [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany), what is the best way to get the last member added?  This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492431/access-intermediary-model-values-django) but what I want to do is to be able to do this.

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=1)
group.get_last_member_added()  #This is by ('-date_added')
<Person: FOO>
```

I think the best way is through a manager but how do you do this on an intermediary model?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a manager! Unless you'd like to add some kind of try/except in case there is no latest member.

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=1)
latest_person = group.members.latest('membership__date_joined')
```

Comment: Continually amazed at the power of Django!  Thanks!